# /proc directory for windows

Tags: windows, security, data-mining

I ,and my friends, are doing a major project on HIDS(host based intrusion detection system). I think i know the sources of information i need for the analysis but i dont know how to get them. These are **system logs, memory usage, process lists, daemon status, service status, kernel modules** and so on. I think i can get the system logs but the others i dont know how to.
I know there is a /proc directory in linux but what shall i do for windows?
Thanks..and i am desperate to have my project started..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in python but there are windows API functions to get all of that info.  For memory usage you can use the [performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373214%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Process list are available though [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function. Daemon status and service status kinda means the same thing in windows and is available from the [service functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685942%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there is not a single place to look on Windows. You might be able to use cygwin to find some information.

- System logs are in XML format in Event Viewer. See [eventquery.vbs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772995%28WS.10%29.aspx) and [eventtriggers.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773308%28WS.10%29.aspx) which might help.
- `netstat` will find any network information

Your best bet for the most complete single source is Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) queries, which use a language similar to SQL, allow you to query all kinds of system information. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) has a lot of links to resources.